# Lengthen the horizontal area for signature block in a letter

Tags: letters

I have a generic rec letter template which I update as needed. It's great, except that the long name of the sub-department I work for wraps in my signature block and I don't want it to. Specifically, my signature block renders like this:

```
My Name
My Title
The Pretty Long Name of the 
Sub-Department That I Work For 
My University
```

While I'd prefer:

```
My Name
My Title
The Pretty Long Name of the Sub-Department That I Work For 
My University
```

I have tried moving the whole signature block to the left with `\longindentation=15em`, but it doesn't seem to have actually *widened* the block (just translated it).

Any help appreciated!

Below is the totality of my source:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em} % indentation of first line of paragraphs


\signature{My Name \\ My Title \\ The Pretty Long Name of the Sub-Department That I Work For \\ My University}
\address{My Name \\ My Office Address \\ My University}

\longindentation=15em % move the signature block a bit to the left so it's not starting at the center

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Recipient Department \\ Recipient Organization or University}

\opening{\noindent To whom it may concern:} % \noindent leaves this paragraph unindented

This is my letter which almost always consists of three paragraphs of text.

Here's the middle paragraph.

Here's the concluding paragraph.

\vspace{2em}
\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

letter class places the signature in

```
 \hspace*{\longindentation}\fi
  \parbox{\indentedwidth}
```

so you can increase the length `\indentedwidth` but if you increase it too much you will need to reduce `\longindentation` so it stays on the page.

Comment: Thanks very much! `\indentedwidth=50em` did exactly what I was looking for.